# Replace tokens in large array

Tags: java, arrays, replace, token

i have this code in main class

```
String slangOutput = msglower;
                    for (String[] replacement : sd.replacements){
                        if (slangOutput.length() == replacement[0].length()){
                            slangOutput = slangOutput.replace(replacement[0], replacement[1]);
                        }
                    }
```

and have this > 5000 arrays in slangDictionary class:

```
String [][] replacements ={
            {"*4u","kiss for you"},
            {"*67"," unknown"},
            {"*eg*","evil grin"},
            {"07734","hello"},
            {"0day","software illegally obtained before it was released"},
            {"0noe","oh no"},
......
```

i'm pretty sure that java has limited size of array, and when i run this code it's only replacing 1000 first array. How to handle this and optimize the computation. thanks for helping

Comment: Java doesn't limit anything, did you perform tests to prove it?

Comment: Btw I don't understand your intention to compare word length before replace attempt. Is it some kind of optimization? It can be done in more optimized and elegant way.

Comment: What does `slangOutput`/`msglower` contain? Please give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java arrays are not limited in size unless you're getting to approximately Integer.MAX_VALUE. That is not the problem.

The first problem is that you're using the wrong data structure. This is not what arrays are for. You want to map some strings to other strings, so this is exactly the case in which you should use a map. Your `replacements` should be of type `Map<String, String>`, specifically using the `HashMap` implementation. You can fill the map using a static initializer - in your class, something like

```
private static Map<String, String> replacements;
static {
   replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
   replacements.put("*4u", "kiss for you");
   .....
}
```

Then, the `replace` method of strings isn't very fast. It's good when you need to do a few replacements without using much code, but it's really bad if you're using it in a loop thousands of times. One way to speed it up would be to use a `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(msglower);
for (Entry<String, String> replacement : replacements.entrySet()) {
  int start = sb.indexOf(replacement.geyKey(), 0);
  while (start >= 0) {
    int end = start + replacement.getKey().length();
    sb.replace(start, end, replacement.getValue());
    start = sb.indexOf(replacement.getKey(), start + replacement.getValue().length());
  }
}
```

I haven't tried to compile the above, but it should be the right idea. And using `StringBuilder` that way will make the replacements run much faster.

Comment: sorry, 

after i code this 
' for (Map.Entry<String, String> replacement : sd.replacements){
... } '

it says that required: array or java.lang.iterable
found: Map<String, String>

Comment: @RickyKristianButar-butar Right, that is the sort of thing I miss when not compiling. Should be `replacements.entrySet()` in the loop - edited. You should be able to find things like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Java array max size is not limited by 1000  - check the lenght property of your array, it is of int type. Without checking the spec, theoretically it is 2^31-1 = 2147483647, which is Integer.MAX_VALUE . So, you will not hit the max size after 1000 elements - it is somewhere else (memory?)

Comment: sorry, i just edited. it has 5000 properties in a array

Comment: when i compile it, error comes

error: code too large